# ICEFaces 1.7.2 and Websphere Application Server 7

Tags: java, icefaces, websphere-7

We recently migrated from WAS6 to WAS7. One of our application, which was working perfectly fine in WAS6 is not working in WAS7 with following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/sun/faces/util/Util.verifyFactoriesAndInitDefaultRenderKit(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)V
at com.ibm.faces.context.MultipartFacesContextFactoryImpl.getFacesContext(MultipartFacesContextFactoryImpl.java:73)
```

The piece of code, which is giving that error is

```
FacesContextFactory contextFactory  = (FacesContextFactory)
             FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.FACES_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
         facesContext = contextFactory.getFacesContext(
             request.getSession().getServletContext(), request, response, lifecycle);
```

Found these info while debugging the app in WAS6 vs WAS7
    contextfactory: com.ibm.faces.context.MultipartFacesContextFactoryImpl - JSF-IBM.jar - WAS7
    contextfactory: com.icesoft.faces.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl - icefaces.jar - WAS6

I tried some suggestions like creating a Shared Lib and associating that to the EAR and changing the class loader schemes from "Parent Last" to "Parent First".

But no matter what I do, In WAS7 I am getting MultipartFacesContextFactoryImpl as the value of contextFactory.

I tried to replace 1.7.2 with 1.8 version of icefaces.jar and icefaces-comps.jar. But still the same result.

Please help. Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that WAS6 used Java 5 as native and WAS7 uses Java 6.  Try recompiling your classes with Java 6.